# Need to override proxy in loop in Selenium Chrome Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I know there are many questions floating around this topic. But, I have a different scenario but same error.

I am able to set the proxy by setting `ChromeOptions` in chrome driver.

But, I need to set a new proxy URL each time I create a Chrome Driver object. I am creating driver object in a loop.

I am able to set the proxy with ip:port first time. But when I try to update the proxy with different URL(which can be a wrong IP:Port), current proxy does not override previous proxy.

I am testing this scenario to provide correct proxy first time and bad proxy second time. Second time, URL connects successfully which it should be.

Please help what I am missing in code. Following is the code I am using to set proxy:

```
for(String proxyUrl: listOfUrls){     
     Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
     proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyUrl)
     .setSslProxy(proxyUrl);
     proxy.setNoProxy("");

     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
     options.addArguments("--verbose");
     options.addArguments("--whitelisted-ips=''");

    //I am setting it as just an option. Only using this does not work.
     options.addArguments("--proxy-server="+proxyUrl);

     //This is mandatory to set the proxy
     options.setProxy(proxy);

     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
     driver.get(url);
     ... some code
     driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe not the best solution but you can try: 
You can use urllib2 check if the proxy is working then start the driver,

```
import urllib2, socket

socket.setdefaulttimeout(180)

# read the list of proxy IPs in proxyList
proxyList = ['172.30.1.1:8080', '172.30.3.3:8080'] # there are two sample proxy ip

def is_bad_proxy(pip):    
    try:        
        proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': pip})        
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)        
        req=urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com')  # change the url address here
        sock=urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:        
        print 'Error code: ', e.code
        return e.code
    except Exception, detail:

        print "ERROR:", detail
        return 1
    return 0

for item in proxyList:
    if is_bad_proxy(item):
        print "Bad Proxy", item
    else:
        print item, "is working"
```

This code is from: [github](https://github.com/ApsOps/proxy-checker/blob/master/proxy_check.py) thank to @RiccardoAncarani
RiccardoAncarani

Comment: I do not need this check for proxy verification.